# whats wrong with the use of this wordpress function: wp_list_categories()

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

Cant see where I am going wrong with this, any help please?

```
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

//then set the args for wp_list_categories
 $args = array(
    'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth'  => 1,
    'title_li' => __(''),
    'echo' => '0'
    );

$terms_list = wp_list_categories( $args);
if( $terms_list ){
    ?>
    <div id="terms_list">
        <ol>
            <?php echo $terms_list; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?php
};

// this line is just here for debug to confirm that we have the right item  - it is not a part of the design or normal functionality
 echo  '<h1>terms_id: ' . $current_term->term_id . ' name: ' . $current_term->name . ' and: ' . $current_term->taxonomy . '</h1>'; 
?>
```

so the function causing the problem is wp_list_categories() and it is returning nothing at all. I've checked the term is correct and it does have posts, and it does have children which also have posts. Andy help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try changing hierarchical to 1 instead of true (it is set to true by default accoreding to [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Comment: i think you need to add `if (isset($terms_list)) {`

Comment: also no need for `;` at the end of if statement

Comment: No neither suggestion from @Howlin or Hareesh is making a difference, thanks guys.

Comment: @Hareesh ; is superfluous I agree but makes no difference.

Comment: check you getting it right  `var_dump($terms_list);` outside the if condition, also try `'echo' => false`

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the arguments in the $args array and adding them back one by one?

Comment: var_dump returns bool(false) , changing echo to false makes no diference, if I remove all clauses from $args except child_of as we might expect, I get output but it returns default categories as a bullet, and then one lines stating 'No categories' with var_dump = NULL ......If I leave the taxonomy clause as the sole condition or paired with child_of, again we have no output...bool(false)

Comment: Copied your code into my local to debug but it works for me. Can you try disabling plugins or checking your theme's functions.php for any code/hooks that might be conflicting with the function wp_list_categories?

Comment: ok did you getting the correct value in `$current_term`?

Comment: @ange008 well that's good to know, so will be leaving the issue until tomorrow however until I check it out. Thanks for your feedback. Need to sleep.

Comment: We tried the above code, and it is working fine. Try setting value for, 'depth' to '0', to display all category hierarchy. 

Even if the category is assigned, to post or not, it will get listed.

Please recheck $current_term value. Whether it receives proper values for those having sub-category.

Answer (score 0):

`$current_term->term_id` is of type *string*. The `child_of` parameter expects an *integer*.

Try doing this:

```
$args = array(
    'child_of' => (int) $current_term->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth'  => 1,
    'title_li' => __(''),
    'echo' => '0'
);
```

Comment: Oh interesting @henrywright I missed that one. Unfortunately even when typecasting as per your suggestion, there is still no output.

Comment: There's no need to type cast here, $current_term->term_id is already of type _int_.

Comment: @ange008 the Codex states `$current_term->term_id` is type **string**. If the Codex is wrong then please tell me and I'll update it. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by#Return_Values

Comment: @henrywright Yes it is wrong in this case, doing a `var_dump($current_term->term_id);` returns `int n`.